# Could not find function "lucas_Lehmer2"

Tags: r, function

I am running a simple R program that I have recently written in the last month. I used to be able to call R functions from it. I am calling lucas_Lehmer2 right now ...

```
two <- as.bigz(2)
merNums <- two^p-1
t1 <- lucas_Lehmer2(p,merNums)
mP <- merNums[t1]
```

When I run the calling R script I get:

Error in lucas_Lehmer2(p, merNums) :
could not find function "lucas_Lehmer2"

I have set the working directory correctly too. I checked that the function name matched the filename too. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what package is that from? have you sourced that library? if its a function witten by you, have you sourced the file that it is in?

Comment: If you're desperate and my answer doesn't help, then see https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Lucas-Lehmer_test#R. I know nothing about it, but it popped up in a search.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it on CRAN. Since you've had it recently (and have not updated or reloaded-completely or started-from-scratch your R), then here's a trick that may find it for you.

I don't have that function, so I'll look for one that I know I have: a function that includes `roxygen` in the function name. (While we know where that is, we'll go through the steps to confirm it.

```r
pkgs <- list.files(.libPaths()[1], pattern = "^NAMESPACE$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
names(pkgs) <- basename(dirname(pkgs))
ptn <- "\\(.*roxygen.*\\)" # you should use lucas_Lehmer
ret <- lapply(pkgs, function(fn) grep(ptn, readLines(fn), value = TRUE))
ret <- ret[lengths(ret) > 0]
str(ret)
# List of 2
#  $ roxygen2: chr [1:3] "export(roxygenise)" "export(roxygenize)" "useDynLib(roxygen2, .registration=TRUE)"
#  $ usethis : chr "export(use_roxygen_md)"
```

In this case, there are two packages installed in my instance of R-4 that have functions that contain `roxygen`.

For my search, since many many many packages have a header row that says `"# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand"`, so I had to make my search a little more specific to include surrounding parens. One could make this search significantly more specific or general. In your case, I think finding anything with `lucas_Lehmer` might be sufficient, no need for regex fanciness.

This trick will work only if it is in your `.libPaths()[1]`. For most installations, this is where non-standard packages are installed, but your case might be different. If that is true, then iterate over each path within `.libPaths()` until you find something. If none of these work, perhaps look in library paths for older versions of R. For instance, if you recently upgraded to R-4.0, then your `.libPaths()` entry likely includes `"4.0"` somewhere in the path; look for a neighboring older-version directory and look *there* until you find the specific package. Once you find it in an older-version-package, then you'll need to `install.packages` it into R-4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: any luck finding your function?